# Git lfs fetch from a local bare repo? Or other local copy of LFS files?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

My group was collaborating with another group on a project, and we set up a GitHub organization for the collaboration. Now that the collaboration ended, we are about to delete the organization from GitHub, and I need to make a local copy of the repositories my team worked on.

My understanding is that `git clone --bare <url>` is a good way to do this, but some of these repos use LFS. I was hoping I could follow the instructions [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository-that-contains-git-large-file-storage-objects), except instead of pushing to a new remote, clone the bare repository locally. In other words, I wanted to do this:

```
git clone --bare git@github.com:<organization>/somerepo.git
cd somerepo.git/
git lfs fetch --all
cd ..
git clone somerepo.git/
cd somerepo
# View source code, build, checkout other branches, etc.
```

and I was hoping LFS would fetch from the bare repo directly. Unfortunately, as I was afraid, it doesn't seem to work that way.

Is there a way to accomplish that, or otherwise obtain a local working copy of a repository--with local copies of all the branches and tags and all the large files? If it matters, we don't need to be able to add new commits, just checkout different branches and access all the files.

Comment: What version of Git LFS are you using?  `git lfs env` will tell you.

Comment: @bk2204 git-lfs/2.9.0 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.13.1), git version 2.17.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Git LFS 2.9.0, it's possible to clone from a local repository if you specify it as an absolute file URL.  Local paths are not supported, but they will be in Git LFS 2.10.0.

In addition, you currently need to use `%3a` instead of a colon if you're on Windows.  You're not, but other folks are, and it's a common source of issues.  This requirement should also go away in 2.10.0.

So essentially, the URL that you use to clone with Git should look something like the following: `file:///home/nick/checkouts/somerepo.git`.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather [transfer your repository from your organisation to your user account](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/transferring-a-repository).

> If the transferred repository uses Git Large File Storage, all Git LFS objects are automatically moved.
>   This transfer occurs in the background, so if you have a large number of Git LFS objects or if the Git LFS objects themselves are large, it may take some time for the transfer to occur.
>
> Before you transfer a repository that uses Git LFS, make sure the receiving account has enough data packs to store the Git LFS objects you'll be moving over.
>   For more information on adding storage for user accounts, see "[Upgrading Git Large File Storage.](https://help.github.com/en/articles/upgrading-git-large-file-storage)"

Comment: There are two issues with this: First, it's not "our" repository (both groups contributed), so removing it from the other group would not be great. We just want a local copy. Second, our group does not have an organization account of our own, anyway.